# Running bibtex4word with Office 2016 + TexLive 2015

Tags: bibtex, texlive, msword

I've installed bibtex4word exactly per instructions, and the macro seems to be working from within Word, but I don't think Word is able to get bibtex to run and/or produce output correctly (bibtex, and my entire texlive setup works fine otherwise). In experimenting with the test file Test4w.doc, Word reports,

```
Missing Bibtex log file. C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\bibtex4word.blg
```

(where *Me* is obviously my Windows login name) following by a Visual Basic error dialog,

```
Run-time error '1'
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

That's it. bibtex4word.blg is indeed missing, and is never created anywhere. I've followed all steps in terms of path and environmental variable declarations: BIBEXE is declared and valid (I can open a shell, type %BIBEXE% and get a bibtex response), I've added OPENOUT_ANY = r in C:\texlive\2015\texmf-dist\web2c\texmf.cnf, registered DLLs, Word Object Library is enabled, etc. I just wondered if anyone had any experience with this and could offer any insight into what I might try next. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I also recommend you to also take a look at Mendeley in company with jabref. I think by this way you will have much less

Comment: Similar setup here (Word 2010+TexLive 2016, Win7 64bit). On the first attempt, I got the same error. After executing the same steps you've mentioned, it's working. Well, not _exactly_ the same: I added `OPENOUT_ANY = r` to `C:\texlive\2016\texmf.cnf`. Maybe try this!?
Btw, does anyone know if the author of Bibtex4Word, Mike Brookes, is here on StackExchange?